# Starting Rails server on boot on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, startup, boot, webrick

I'm pretty new to rails and trying to figure things out, I looked online but not much luck.

I have some servers that are running rails on startup without using rc.local at all, but I can't figure out why.

All I need is for rails to start on boot in production mode on port 80 (instead of 3000, as the rest of the servers also start on port 80).

Any ideas?

ATM relaying on webrick

Comment: If you insist on starting on boot you need to run the script from your initrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at setting up nginx with ruby enterprise edition.

Comment: I am looking for something without using nginx as the other servers arent using it

Comment: apache, lighttpd, nginx. those are your best bets. with nginx you could also run webrick or mongrel using fastcgi. webrick is not safe it's for dev mode only.

Comment: I installed nginx with rails module, installed passenger, now when i go to the rails application folder it says it doesnt find a lot of gems. I already did "bundle update"

Comment: It says "Could not find passenger (>=0) amongst" and a lot of gems here

Comment: and those are all in your Gemfile.

Comment: So how do I fix this so the server starts?

Comment: @JosephLeBrech link is now dead

Answer (score 0):

Check out Phusion Passenger. It supports both the standard Apache web server and Nginx web server.

http://www.modrails.com/

Comment: Nothing for webrick starting on boot?

Comment: webrick is not recommended for production machines. Passenger is a good way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I've only used webrick for non-production so it's hasn't really been a issue. So short of writing the startup script yourself and using rc.local I don't have a good suggestion. Any reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: After installing passenger, it would boot up on its own on reboot or ?

Comment: It hooks into your web server. Apache or Nginx depending on which one you are running.